# Is it possible to set text on single button of UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one UITableView having two buttons on cell.I want to set text on button from picker view and date picker.On selection of Done button for UIPickerView I can set text to firstButton. when I am selecting date from UIDatePicker for secondButton, my firstButton text gets changes.

```
var selectedIndexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

DataTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexpath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Here is my function on done button click:

```
@IBAction func pickerDoneButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cell = DataTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: selectedIndexpath) as! DataTableViewCell
    cell.frequencyButton .setTitle(pickerDataSource[frequencyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    DataPicker.hidden = true
    pickerToolbar.hidden = true
    DataPickerView.hidden = true
    DataTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexpath], withRowAnimation: .None)

}
```

I have reload tableview row on done button action.Please suggest me better way to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the more code which shows how you're setting the text on both of your buttons using the pickerview.

Comment: Please check my edited question.I added my button function to set text on button

Answer (score 0):

Set tags for buttons according to the indexPath of the cell and access the buttons like 
 `let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(yourButtonTag) as? UIButton` and i dont think you need to reload the whole tableview for this purpose.
Hope it helps.